# Focus Lost event for a Winforms TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Which event should I use for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Control.Leave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx) or [Control.LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx):

> When you change the focus by using the keyboard (<kbd>⇆</kbd>, <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⇆</kbd>, and so on), by calling the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.select.aspx) or [SelectNextControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol.aspx) methods, or by setting the [ContainerControl.ActiveControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol.aspx) property to the current form, focus events occur in the following order:
>
> 1. [Enter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx)
> 2. [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx)
> 3. [Leave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx)
> 4. [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx)
> 5. [Validated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated.aspx)
> 6. [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx)
>
> When you change the focus by using the mouse or by calling the [Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) method, focus events occur in the following order:
>
> 1. [Enter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx)
> 2. [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx)
> 3. [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx)
> 4. [Leave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx)
> 5. [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx)
> 6. [Validated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated.aspx)
>
> If the [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation.aspx) property is set to false, the [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) and [Validated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated.aspx) events are suppressed.

Comment: This is strange, when I lose the focus with mouse, I don't get Validated event to fire for some reason.

Comment: Some controls may not fire it; also CausesValidation may be set to `false`. And `Validated` is not strictly a focus event, as in, you shouldn't use it as a "focus lost" event. It's for validation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Control.LostFocus.

Comment: It's not listed under TextBox property editor. Do you know why?

Comment: Just not shown in the property editor.  You can add it from code behind.  If Control.Leave is there as Johannes suggested you could use that as well.

Comment: It is not shown in the properties window because the event is marked with [BrowsableAttribute(false)] 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

'Control.LostFocus'

Comment: It's not listed under TextBox property editor. Do you know why?