# How can I tell if my program is the one that's focused?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, focus

I can't find a good answer to this...

What I'm asking specifically is, how can I tell if my program (winforms) is visible to the user, and it's focused? For example, when you use Skype, it can tell whether it is the one focused and visible or not. If you receive a Skype IM and the program is either not visible (hidden behind other windows)/minimized it will make the notification sound. If Skype knows that it's the one with the focus, the *top most application*, it won't bother to make the notification because it assumes you're using it.

Now, I've tried `if (this.Focused == true)`, but it doesn't seem to work at all. It can't tell that I'm giving focus to Windows Explorer and that my own program is at the back of it, not focused and greyed out at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tested it out and it works just the way I wanted it! I can check if `Form.ActiveForm` is null: if it's null, then it doesn't have focus; if it's not null, it has focus!

Answer (score 1):

An easier way of doing what you want is by using events.

Here is an excellent post about that https://stackoverflow.com/a/1786376/2692994

Inside the event, you put whatever you want to do with your form.
^
I added the above since that is probably what Skype uses. If you want to check at any time if it's focused or not, just make a "public bool focused = true;" and set it inside of the events to true or false.

Comment: I've tried both the `this.Leave` and the `this.LostFocus` event, but it doesn't fire when I lose the focus of the form... Does it not work when I use the `LostFocus`/`Leave` event of the form?

Comment: Can you please post more info, other than the Focus not working. Give us what your are intending to do.

Comment: The event didn't trigger when my form lost/got focus... It basically did nothing... Thankfully, I found the answer to my own question!