# Dynamically update textbox when clicked away

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a very old Windows Form app written by someone else that does not run well under newer operating systems so I am replicating it in C# for my own personal use on a newer PC.  I have 2 Textboxes, `textBox1` has a default value of `1`, `textBox2` is set `Read Only`.  I have the below code placed in the Form1() method so that it has an initial calculated value on opening.

What I want to do is get the value of `textBox1`, multiply it by `360` then update the value of `textBox2` with the result.  Now I think this is easy via the following:

```
textBox2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * 360).ToString();
```

But I also want to do this dynamically so I can change the value in `textBox1` to `2`, click into another textbox on the Windows Form and `textBox2` changes to `640`, then I could click back into `textBox1`, change the value to `4` and then after clicking into another textbox again the value changes to `1280`.  I have seen examples of Background Workers which I found really confusing, and anyway, this is an extremely simple calculation so the end user is never going to notice a slight pause while it is calculated and the text value updated.  I was hoping there was a simpler way to achieve this result.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You may need to handle the events specified in https://stackoverflow.com/q/1786369/30594 for the textbox1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ramesh, I was able to solve this.  I went into Events for `textBox`, added a Leave event and added my calculating code in there.  Now when I click away from the box, it calculates the value in `textBox2` based on the value in `textBox1`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered registering events? Specifically OnTextChange.  All you have to do is register an event handler function for the OnTextChange event that will run whenever you type a number in the textbox Something like:

```
textbox1.OnTextChange=someFunc;
...
```